# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null in JavaScript webshare api

Tags: javascript, jekyll

I am trying to implement web share api of android chrome in jekyll posts page. Below is my code. 
my code is in `_layout/post.html`.

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('.share-btn2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    if(navigator.share) {
      navigator.share({
        title: '{{ page.title }}',
        url: {{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}
      })
      .then(() => console.log('Success'))
      .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
    }

  });

</script>
```

`<button class="btn btn-danger shadow-sm my-2 my-sm-0 share-btn2" type="submit" value="submit">More</button>`.

Now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`error in console.
https://govtexam.jus.in/maharashtra/2018/12/29/11.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are binding an event before the DOM is loaded. Just wrap it in with `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { // <-- add this wrapper
  document.querySelector('.share-btn2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    if (navigator.share) {
      navigator.share({
          title: '{{ page.title }}',
          url: '{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}'
        })
        .then(() => console.log('Success'))
        .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
    }

  });
}); // <---DOMContentLoaded closing
```

Comment: actually after the document is loaded, there is still no element with class name `share-btn2`...

Comment: @TangYun if you see the button it does have `share-btn2"` class. I am sure it is due to the issue i mentioned.

Comment: I can only find a button with class `share-btn5`, if you visit the page: https://govtexam.justinechacko.in/maharashtra/2018/12/29/11.html

Answer (score 0):

you don't have element with class 'share-btn2'. so the `document.querySelector('.share-btn2') returns null.

Please add the class `share-btn2` to the button you wish to bind the click event listener.